# crm ifd username and password

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

i'd like to know how can get the user name and his password and use it when i set the crmservice connection

```
CrmDiscoveryService disco = new CrmDiscoveryService();
disco.Url = "https://localhost/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx";

//Retrieve a list of available organizations from the CrmDiscoveryService Web service.
RetrieveOrganizationsRequest orgRequest = new RetrieveOrganizationsRequest();

HERE I WANT TO PUT THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD FROM THE SIGNIN PAGE
// Substitute an appropriate domain, username, and password here.
orgRequest.UserId = domain + "\\" + username;
orgRequest.Password = password;
RetrieveOrganizationsResponse orgResponse = (RetrieveOrganizationsResponse)disco.Execute(orgRequest);
```

thanks to the helper :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the IFD signin page?  There is no way for you to pull the user's credentials from that page.  If you need the user's credentials you'll need to pull them in on a custom page.

You can also accomplish the orgrequest using the UseDefaultCredentials property which will use the current user's credentials:

```
CrmDiscoveryService disco = new CrmDiscoveryService();
disco.Url = "https://localhost/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx";
disco.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Or you can use an [HttpContext/HttpRequest auth](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/81f8ba82-981d-40dd-893d-3add67436478) if you're doing this on a custom page.

Comment: tnx for the answer i will do that